# laravel migrate revert when stuck half-way

Tags: php, laravel, migrate, artisan-migrate

I ran laravel migration for given `path dir` only in new database.

Only migrations file from `database/dmf_migrations` directory is run.

And then half-way I get this `Base table already exists` error.

Here's the last migration run with batch no. 127:
[image]

I want to delete this existing table and run migrate again.

After deleting the table, can I continue with `php artisan migrate --path=database/dmf_migrations` or do I need to reset or rollback?

Comment: Try Php artisan migrate:fresh —path=database/dmf_migrations

Answer (score -1):

If there is no data in the tables then you can just run

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --path=database/dmf_migrations
```

It will drop all tables and re-run all migrations.

**If you database has other tables or data, please don't use this command.**